# Analysing data using the column name

Tags: excel

I have the following data.

```html
Z Y Z Z 
A1 A2 A3 A4 Total
1 2 5 10 16
2 3 5 11 18
3 4 6 12 21
4 4 7 12 23
```

I want to sum the rows using Just Zs ( the name of columns). I have a big data set, so I want to write a function to find out Zs in the whole sheet and the then sum them (Total).

Any Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done with SUMIF():

```
=SUMIF($1:$1,"Z",2:2)
```

[image]

**NOTE**

With the above formula it is using full row references so DO NOT put "Z" on top of the total column or it will throw circular errors.

If you want to have "Z" above it then you need to define the ranges:

```
=SUMIF(A$1:D$1,"Z",A2:D2)
```

Comment: Darn [Occam and his razor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Occam%27s_razor)!  (this is why you're the Excel gold star and I'm just a novice! :P)

Comment: Hm, I tried this it wouldn't sum multiple columns with "Z" headers, which is why I have the more convoluted formula. Drats, I guess I didn't try hard enough.

Comment: Scott @ thank you can you explain 1:1 and 2:2 please

Comment: @user1309 see my note in the answer.  You may need to refresh the screen.  They are full row references.

Comment: Thank you Scott for  your help

Answer (score 0):

How does this work:

`=Sum(If(A$1:D$1="Z",$A$2:$D$100))`

Assuming your headers are in row 1, columns A to D, and your data starts in row 2, and goes to row 100.

Comment: @ScottCraner - Yes indeed! Typo on my part.

Comment: @ScottCraner - ahahahahah I'm just going to go home. :P (updated, thanks for your help :D)